# How can i perform automatic updates (of course by checking) a boolean field from the gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I already enable the linqdatasource in Advanced Options.

Code below:

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ValidData" HeaderText="Valid Risk Item" 
            SortExpression="ValidData" />
```

Comment: You are right.  It was originally there.  How come it's now showing?

Comment: wierd.. now nothing is showing at all other than the question...

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ValidData" HeaderText="Valid Risk Item" SortExpression="ValidData" />

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ValidData" HeaderText="Valid Risk Item" 
                SortExpression="ValidData" />

Comment: I rolled it back to Glen's edit. You must add your code in a code block by either selecting it and clicking the code block icon (0s and 1s), or selecting it and using `CTRL+K`, or by manually adding 4 spaces in front of your code.

Comment: thank you Ahmad Mageed.  I didn't know that.  Now let get back to my original scenario, any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514963.aspx